# copying a fragment that starts with a particular pattern

Tags: bash, awk, sed, grep

Is there a way to copy (using sed) from a text file, the fragment that starts with a particular word, all the way down the text file. For example to copy the fragment in below that starts with Scotland:

```
... However, if we characterise viewers as likely to watch both 
BBC 1 and Reporting Scotland or both STV and ITV News, in 
succession, the two experiences diverge further than is ...
```

The output should be:

```
Scotland or both STV and ITV News, in 
succession, the two experiences diverge further than is ...
```

The output can replace the original file.

Comment: fixed the formatting. It can have multiple lines

Comment: I guess the output's 2nd line should be "succession, the two..", isn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `awk` I would say:

```
awk '!f && /Scotland/ {sub(".*Scotland","Scotland"); f=1} f' file
```

For your given input this returns:

```
Scotland or both STV and ITV News, in 
succession, the two experiences diverge further than is ...
```

The idea here is to keep a flag to see if a line should be printed or not. It defaults to "no" and is set to "yes" once `Scotland` is found. In that particular line, all text before `Scotland` is removed.

---

> is there a way to speed up this when the file is too big (5millions of
>   lines for instance)?
>
> One thing I noticed is that the word I am looking for always occurs in
>   the last 10 lines of the file.

In this case, you may want to start reading the file from the end. This can be done with `tac`. Then, just print everything up to the line in which `Scotland` is found, where you print it and then exit the script. Finally, `tac` again to get the output in its original order:

```
tac file | awk '/Scotland/ {sub(".*Scotland","Scotland"); print; exit} 1' | tac
```

Comment: Amazing. Works like a charm :)

Comment: is there a way to speed up this when the file is too big (5millions of lines for instance)?

Comment: Interesting. In this case, you may want to use `tac`, as described in my edited answer.